# validate that an email address contains "@" and "." 

Tags: java, email, validation, email-address

i need to validate that an inserted email address contains "@" and "." without a regular expression.
Can somebody to give me "java code" and "structure chart" examples please?

Comment: Do you mean whether the address is *just* "@" or "."? Or validate that they *contain* "@" and ".".

Comment: Did you ... actually look on SO? (Or actually try anything?) This sort of question is far from "rare".

Comment: sorry, validate if email consist "@" and "."

Comment: "somebody give me" usually doesn't work - show what you have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I *suspect* you're after something like:

```
if (!address.contains("@") || !address.contains("."))
{
    // Handle bad address
}
```

EDIT: This is far from a complete validation, of course. It's barely even the *start* of validation - but hopefully this will get you going with the particular case you wanted to handle.

Comment: Still rather bad. ".@" isn't even close to a valid address :)

Comment: @Kaj: Absolutely. It's far from a complete validation - I'm only answering what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`commons-validator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator) , Specifically [`EmailValidator.isValid()`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/api-1.3.1/org/apache/commons/validator/EmailValidator.html#isValid%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I love the way this is absolutely, completely undocumented what the function checks for.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, the only was to validate an email address is to send a email with a validation link or code.
I tried many of the validator but they are not complete because the email addresses can be very loose ...

Comment: Even if you are able to send email to an address, that does not prove it is "valid" (assuming you define "valid" as "follows the RFCs."

Comment: @Brian : "with a validation link or code" i.e. by clicking on the link the user confirms that the provided email is a working mean of communication. I also explored the appache utils but we had some foreign clients complaining that our system use to deny their valid email address.

Comment: I was disputing your claim that successfully sending an email means the email is valid.  I.e., even if the user clicks the link, their email address may be invalid (they might even be clicking the link in a catch-all or whatever).  It's a pedantic point, but it does become relevant when you have more than one mail-sending system.  Some APIs are a bit finicky about sending e-mail to "invalid" e-mail addresses.  E.g., sending to an e-mail address containing an umlaut will only succeed in with some mail systems and APIs.

Answer (score 1):

```
int dot = address.indexOf('.');
int at = address.indexOf('@', dot + 1);

if(dot == -1 || at == -1 || address.length() == 2) {
  // handle bad address
}
```

This is not complete solution. You will have to check for multiple occurances of @ and address with only '.' and '@'.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.indexOf if you aren't allowed to use regexp, and but I would adwise you to not validate the address during input.

It's better to send an activation email.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Java Mail API. Specifically, here:

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the first '@', then check if what you have at the left of the '@' is a valid string (i.e. it doesn't have spaces or whatever). After that you should search in the right side for a '.', and check both strings, for a valid domain.

This is a pretty weak test. Anyway I recommend using regular expressions.