# How to make email textbox format

Tags: java

I hava an application that has a register frame with all relavant textboxes and combo boxes and buttons.now my problem is when i enter an email on the email textbox it saves in my database regardless of the nonsense i've put in.i want to make sure that the user puts the correct format of the email e.g "example@blhablha.com" even if this email doesn't exist but atleast in looks like an email address im using java by the way.

Your help is highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: have you tried google? I'm pretty sure this issue is heavily covered.

Comment: Seriously, do some research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email

Comment: Apparently he has not tried google, but still, even if this is an easy answer, as a beginner he/she may not know how to search this (ie that it is a client side code, hence jscript or vbscript and is called "validation") he should have the right to post a simple question here without zillions of downvotes...

Comment: His other questions are about Java, so I'm going to assume he got that part right.

Comment: @BeQl no. "textbox check email java" is enough, it's harder to find a title for this site.

Comment: @Matten actually you are right, touche

Comment: It's one thing when you try to do something in an ass-backwards way, it's a different thing to ask a VERY common question instead of googling OR searching stackoverflow... even tho it searches for you as you type your issue.

A little effort is required. All I see here is "i want" but no "i tried X and got error Y"

Comment: at least now they learned the importance of searching and trial and error :P

Comment: @Shark thanks for the insult i will bear it in mind.....!

Comment: It is not an insult, it's advice. You are more likely to get answers when you say "i tried X and got errors A,B,C,D...Z" than "I want this". Then we know how you think and can get some insight into what you're trying to do, and can think of why those reasons that you tried might not be working... Saying "i want code that does X" is slightly better than saying "look at this code, it doesn't work!!1!1!" which really gets us nowhere. You need to help us help you, not just throw it in our face and expect a correct answer. Sometimes you'll get it, other times I won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Matten criticizing someone is one thing but making them feel stupid is another thing just remember that,everytime you make a comment.Kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [validate that an email address contains "@" and "." ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955739/validate-that-an-email-address-contains-and)

Comment: @LazarusMasoga sorry that wasn't my intention. It just happens too often that someone asks a question with a title that would solve the problem when entered into any search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really complicated to validate an email address, still there are a bunch of regular expression you can find on the web that will check certain important things, like this one for example `^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$`. Unfortunately I don't think there is an *ultimate* regex that will catch every "non-sense" you can find in an email address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into javascript email validation, try following this https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140426/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/052899-1.shtml

Comment: He said he's using Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Roddy: given the quality of the question, I have to doubt that the original poster really knows the difference.

Comment: Agreed, but I sometimes like to give them the benefit of the doubt unless they prove to be completely hopeless.

Comment: I think he/she means php or (more likely) asp, if you do not know about simple client side validations than you wouldn't be able to get into jsp? or am i wrong?

Comment: Thank you all.even the negative comments thank you but im pretty much sure you were not born as programmers.I guesse you are all entitled to your own opinion.With that well being said thanks again.Have a wonderful day.

Comment: He could be working in Java Swing, or GWT, or half a dozen other GUI-type Java frameworks.

Comment: But until he tells us, all we can do is guess and usually do that incorrectly.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas im using java please look at the email question and if you can solve it that will be much help instead of critisizing.cause at the end of the day it wont help to critisize.Thanks again.

Comment: @LazarusMasoga - I'm not criticizing. I'm saying "try to fix the problem yourself first" or maybe even "try to google the solution first". Because this is a *very* common problem that has been solved *many* times. I even linked a solution in a comment on your original post!

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry dear for that comment it wasn't meant for you kinda made a mistake.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that criticizing comment is acctually meant for you....................!

Comment: @Laz: I understand, and I'm sorry for criticizing you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels its ok.i guesse i'll have to think before asking the questions next time..lol.Will really appreciate the help next time.Thanks